# JSoup - how does HTML structure affect response?

Tags: css, jsoup

[image]Trying to learn JSoup but having problems with response that may be due to structure issues (or stupidity, you tell me!).  I do a simple query for "a[href]" but it only finds a subset 13 (text search tells me there are 162!).  Why does it not find all?

```
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(J_URL).get();
            String srchCSS = "a[href]";
            Elements select = doc.select(srchCSS);
            Iterator<Element> iterator = select.iterator();
            Log.w(TAG, "'" + srchCSS + "' # " + select.size());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Element x = iterator.next();
                System.out.println("'" + srchCSS + "':  " + x.text());
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "%%% COMPLETE %%%");
```

I want to get the text from 'p' (see RED arrow).  The a[href] above it is *NOT* being found?!?

Comment: It is possible that the page you are loading is dynamic page, so parts of it are being loaded with javascript, which is not supported by jsoup.

Comment: will parsing the file get the dynamic data?

Comment: No. If you save the file, you'll only get the static data, so it's the same. Try to use JSPhantom.